# Sizing beam/header for planned 12' opening

Tags: structural, load-bearing, beam, lumber

I am trying to figure out what sized beam I will need to support the load when opening up the center wall in my home.

[image: Wall from back of house forward]

This opening currently exists, but is only 6ft wide. I am looking it expand that to 12ft. It is currently supported by a 2x10' #3 Pine header.

This is on the first floor of a 3 story home. The joists run from the center to front and back of the house, a little under 12ft each way. On the back of the house, the 2nd floor overhangs the first floor by about 2 feet and the joists running to the back extend all the way from the center of the house to the end of the overhang (so the rear joists actually end up being 14ft long and cantilever over the rear wall by 2ft).

Above this wall is the 2nd floor and a roof that is center bearing. I am in Georgia, USA, so there is no presumed snow load.

I had an engineer recommend Microllam 2.0e LVL - 5 1/4x11 1/4” (three ply),14ft long, but I can't find any LVLs in stock right now.

So basically, I would love to know my options for either using #2 Pine or a Steel beam. Preferably the pine if possible since I can get ahold of that the easiest.

Here are some more photos for context:
[image: Wall from front of house back]

[image: Basement Beam directly underneath wall]

Finished! Found the LVL beams:

[New LVL Beam Installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eCqOT.jpg)

Comment: Think it would be best to see the engineer and get their recommendation.  LVLs are usually stronger rating than wood beams so #2 pine would probably be larger than a 6x12 LVL.  The engineer has seen your place and knows more than what we do.

Comment: On this week's episode of "You bet your 3-story house Jenga...."

Comment: Order what the engineer stated, or is this an "I need it now" question?

Comment: Have you tried to figure out the dimensions needed for a header built up of #2 pine to equal the strength of the recommended  Microllam 2.0e LVL - 5 1/4x11 1/4” (three ply),14ft long?  I bet it's going to be significantly larger.

Comment: Don't bet your house on the good will and best intentions of a bunch of internet strangers. The few hundred bucks for a licensed structural engineer are _far_ cheaper than rebuilding when the whole place collapses because you (or we) guessed wrong.

Comment: For everyone referencing my game of Jenga, you'll be happy to know I found some LVLs up to his specs 2 hours away. Just got it installed today and looks great :) [New LVL Beam](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eCqOT.jpg)

Comment: You say it was a “planned opening”.  Does that mean you have adequate footings under each end of that opening?  How big are the footings?  The Code allows 1500 psf without a geotechnical report.

Comment: The Code requires the top plate be nailed into the beam 12” oc staggered along the top of the beam or steel connectors are required as post caps.

Comment: I’ve never seen a vertical splice in an lvl in the middle third of the span. Who made this beam?

Comment: There are 6x6 #2 pine posts under the subfloor where the jacks are which transfer the load down directly to the steel beam underneath. Also, the top plate is nailed to the beam staggered as you said. So, it's not actually a vertical splice, it's just a mark from where the LVL was secured to a pallet in the lumber yard. It's 3 pieces of 1-3/4" x 11-7/8" 2.0E LP SolidStart LVL nailed together according to the manufacturers specs to be used as a beam (12" oc staggered).